# Show JSP for non-supported browsers

Tags: java, html, jsp

Could someone please help me? 
The task - I need to show the modal JSP to the users who are using old browser versions, for example, versions older than 5 previous versions.

I have only validation for Internet Explorer (MSIE, TRIDENT) and it works. But I want my modal JSP to be dependent on the browser version: if the browser is Chrome and the current version is 75 or not older than 5 previous versions (from 75 to 70), then show the JSP file. And the same for Firefox, Opera, Safari, and Edge. Below you can find the working code which included in the existing JSP file from where it runs the browser check and shows my modal JSP, but only for IE.

```java
<%
String browserOutdatedUa = request.getHeader("user-agent");
boolean isIESoInclude = false;
if(browserOutdatedUa != null) {
    browserOutdatedUa = browserOutdatedUa.toUpperCase();
    if(browserOutdatedUa.contains("MSIE") || browserOutdatedUa.contains("TRIDENT")) {
        isIESoInclude = true;
    }
}else {
    browserOutdatedUa = "";
}
if(isIESoInclude) {%>
    <%@include file="include-browser-update.jsp"%>
<%}%>
```

Comment: Bad idea. You should always test browser *feature* availability, not flavor or version of browser. Besides, 5 versions of IE is like a million versions of many other browsers, so a blanket "5 versions" rule seems arbitrary and misguided.

Comment: Are you tied to using just JSP and server side rendering?  Going with React or some other modern client side solutions make life so much easier.

Comment: @Andreas good point, but to check the browser version - I saw this practice on several services, so, that's why I want to try the same for me.
 
I am not meant that I need literally 5 versions like decimal 74.1.23 or 74.0.123, I meant I need only integer versions like 75, 74 or 73. Same for Firefox, I only need 67, 66, 65 - 62, etc.

Comment: @JOTN unfortunately, I am tied to use Java and server side.